# Have a new Google form be started linked to an existing spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

My problem:

I want to create a new form and have it automatically linked to an existing spreadsheet.

It **can** create a new sheet on the existing spreadsheet, but the linking step should be automatic.

Unfortunately, it seems that a copy of a form does not auto-link to the same spreadsheet as the original form, but if there is a solution based on copying forms rather than creating, that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically link a new form to an existing spreadsheet, create the form from the spreadsheet rather than from https://forms.google.com

1. Open the spreadsheet
2. Click the Tools menu then Create a Form

Note: This method allows to add multiple forms to a spreadsheet the same way that it's possible to send the responses from the form editor to an existing spreadsheet even if that spreadsheet already have linked a form.

Comment: I believe your solution will **not** actually work. Simply because the OP is asking about auto-linking a copy of a form -already linked to an existing sheet- to the same sheet based -as an alternative- on *"copying forms rather than creating"* . If one were to try your solution one would find that a new form **cannot** be created because of the already linked one to the existing sheet.You could probably suggest to **first create a copy of the sheet**. All of the form flow functionality would be lost (amongst other things), but... it could be a bare skeleton of a wanna be form.

Comment: the questions says "I want to create a new form and have it automatically linked to an existing spreadsheet"